# Where do you deploy your jive addons in node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, port, jive

I am new to Jive development using Node.js and I see that any addons that you create must be running and reachable via a specific address and port that you define in your `jiveclientconfiguration.json` file. I tried to deploy a tile addon to Azure websites hoping that would work but there is no way to define what port number Azure uses.

Where do you deploy your production Jive addons at and how do you set your configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Some of Jive documentation could be a bit confusing.

here the main steps I followed:

- Sign up for a free account at [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io/).
- Create a new Node.js workspace.
- Install the Node SDK within the Nitrous workspace (npm install jive-sdk -g).
- Create a new tile, app, or whatever you want to create (e.g. jive-sdk create tile-list).
- Update dependencies (npm update).
- Get the URI for your new workspace. (You can use the "Preview" menu to get this... e.g. http://fierce-meteor-71-123263.usw1-1.nitrousbox.com/) Update jiveclientconfiguration.json with this URL.
- Start your service (node app.js).
- Download extension.zip from Nitrous.
- **AND THEN**... upload that extension.zip to the Sandbox and follow the other directions.

I tried this scenario earlier in the week and it worked for me. Let me know if this helps.